# Iterate through Array of Div IDs and change their CSS (One by One)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

I'm trying iterate through and Array of Div ID's and change their CSS (Background color) one after the other. I know how to iterate/loop through the array but they all get selected and the CSS gets added in one go (My only problem is to delay the effect so that each div change one after the other and not at once.) A little help will be much appreciated.

```
    $("#light").click(function(){

            for (var i=0; i < randomArray.length; i++) {

                $("#" + randomArray[i]).css("backgroundColor", "Black"); //How not to change the color at once, but one by one?//

            }
        });
```

Comment: Try `$("#" + randomArray[i])[0].css("backgroundColor", "Black");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can use css animation delay, it's much cleaner and faster.

```
var randomArray = ["elem1", "elem2", "elem3"];

$("#light").click(function(){

     for (var i=0; i < randomArray.length; i++) {

         $("#" + randomArray[i]).addClass("fade-"+i);

     }
});
```

Now you have a list of classes let's say: fade-1, fade-2, fade-3.

in the css:

```
.fade-0,.fade-1,.fade-2{
   background-color: black;
   transition: background-color 1s;
}
.fade-1{
   transition-delay: 1s;
}
.fade-2{
   transition-delay: 2s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try something like this**

```
var ctr = 0;
$("#light").click(function(){
      changeCss(ctr);
})
function changeCss(num){
if(ctr < randomArray.length){
     $("#" + randomArray[num]).css("backgroundColor", "Black");
      ctr++;
         setTimeout(function(){changeCss(ctr)},2000) 
} 
}
```